# Protractor: How to verify text present in the table row?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, javascript, protractor, jasmine

**TestCase: Verify the table ROW contains text.**

To verify text present in Table Row, i tried Using  `"expect.gettext().toContain(datefinal)".`
But ouput returns  `"Expected '7/18/17' to contain undefined."`

**HTML Code:**

```
<table class="table" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
     <tbody>
     <tr class="tableheader">
     <tr>
     <td nowrap="true" align="left">
     <a 
href="/internal/servlet/internalAccountPartner&command=edit"
ALL_User@sb.com</a>
      </td>
      <td align="left">7/18/17</td>
```

**CODE:**

```
 var dateString = "";
 var newDate = new Date();
 // Get the month, day, and year.
 dateString += (newDate.getMonth() + 1) + "/";
 dateString += newDate.getDate() + "/";
 dateString += newDate.getFullYear() - 2000;
 var datefinal = console.log(dateString);
 expect(cells.get(6).getText()).toContain(datefinal);
```

**OUTPUT:**

> Expected '7/18/17' to contain undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assigning `datefinal` to the result of the `console.log()` call - which is `undefined`, hence the error. You meant to assert against `dateString` string:

```
expect(cells.get(6).getText()).toContain(dateString);
```

Comment: I tried the above answer and it is giving me the below error `Error: Invalid Chai property: toContain. Did you mean "contain"?`

Comment: (toConatin) is from Jasmine assertion library. It is correct.

Answer (score 0):

This is the function I've been working on. It takes an event name and searches for it in a grid (no paging to worry about). When found, returns the row# for use elsewhere.

```
verifyEventInGrid(eventName: string) {
        const names = element.all(by.className('ng-star-inserted'));
        names.count().then(function(count) {
            let rowFound = false;
            let i = 0;
            console.log('row count: ', count);
            names.get(i).getText().then(function(rowEventName) {
                do {
                    if (expect(rowEventName).toContain(eventName)) {
                        console.log(i, 'rowEventName:', rowEventName);
                        rowFound = true;
                        return i;
                    }
                    i++;
                } while (i <= count);
                console.log('row found:', i);
            });
        });
    }
```